# How to start a RegEx statement at the 2nd position of a string

Tags: regex

I have a string

`.HACK G.U. VOL. 1 REBIRTH`

I'm using a tool that allows me to specify a RegEx statement that can be used in a replace operation.

I want the RegEx to find all the periods "." that start after the 1st position. The replace operation should return the following.

`.HACK GU VOL 1 REBIRTH`

Thanks

Comment: What language is the regex in. All regex engines are not created equal.

Comment: `TrimLeft(1)` and run your regex.  Keep it simple.

Comment: *I'm using a tool that allows me to specify a RegEx statement that can be used in a replace operation.* . I believe that tool would have a name. Would you mind sharing it?

Comment: I think it's using vb.net's regex, but I can't be sure, and I'm trying to use a single regex to remove a whole bunch of formatting characters after the tool has scrapped information from a variety of websites. 

My actual regex is \*|\?|\(|\)|\+|\||\!|\"|\$|\'|\:|\/|\,|\®|\-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do the trick:

```
(?<!^)(\.)
```

per http://rubular.com/r/w1apzTZLPk

Since Javascript doesn't support negative lookbehind, this can't be done in Javascript, but there are alternatives as discussed in http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript

One approach in this case would be to capture the previous character and replace it with the same content as part of the replacement process, as in:

```
(.)(\.)
```

Note: You don't need to use a capture group for the matching of the literal `.` in either of the above. I just used that technique to highlight the match in Rubular.

Comment: According to the test site I've been using http://www.regextester.com/ that regex doesn't fit my requirement.

Although your test site seems to show it working.

Comment: It worked in my tool, thanks